# CouchDB how to allow external connections only from specific IPs

Tags: security, couchdb, firewall, windows-server

I want to setup a CouchDB Server on my VPS (Windows Server 2012 R2).

When I was reading the CouchDB documentation I learned about how to open the CouchDB server to the public by binding it to a public IP address.

I also know that I have to open the port CouchDB is listening to in my firewall settings.

***But can I configure CouchDB or my windows server to only accept request from specific IPs?***

Because the application which connects to CouchDB will be hosted on another server and by whitelisting the static IP address of this server and blocking all other IPs I want to add an extra layer of "security" to my setup.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer to my question on this website:

https://www.howtogeek.com/112564/how-to-create-advanced-firewall-rules-in-the-windows-firewall/

It answers my question from the "windows server" point of view, if it is possible with CouchDB itself would still be nice to know.